# Sub class models, how I scope the ActiveRecord models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have a user with roles, like so:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

class Manager < User

   def after_initialize do |u|
      u.role = User.roles[:manager] if u.new_record?
   end
```

then this will allow all instances of Manager to automatically have the role populated. However, when I make a call such as `Manager.all` then this will give me back all instances of user, because it's not initialising `Manager`. The expected behaviour would be to receive all users with the role manager. What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are subclassing an active record model you might want to implement single table inheritance by adding a `type` column to the user class.

[Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html)

This will allow manager objects to automatically be initialized as Manager instances instead of User instances.

This will also allow you to call `Manager.all` but somewhat removes the need for the roles relationship.

I personally would choose to stick with either the roles relationship, or subclassing the User model, but not both.

Comment: going this route will basically lose the free helper methods you get with using enum such as `user.manager?` Is there a equivalent for this?

Comment: Yeah, the different solutions here each have their own trade offs.

Single Table Inheritance is good for when you have many classes  which encapsulate the same information, but have different behaviours when operating on that information.

The enum on a user class to indicate role is good if you know your users will only every have a single role.

If users could have many roles (Manager and Supervisor), then perhaps implementing a Has Many Through relationship with a "Role" model might be more appropriate. 

To get the helper methods given by the enum, you can write them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

add this to your user model

```
scope :manager, -> { where(role: "manager") }
```

then when you want to call
all user with manager role

do this

```
User.manager
```

If you still want to use subclass just make it as default scope in your subclass

```
class Manager < User
  default_scope { where(role: "manager") }
end
```